# Docker image create

Tags: centos

I want create own docker image. I use a Dockerfile to create it and want to run only httpd server and mysql client. below can see my edit file. Is my Dockerfile is correct or not?

```
# Dockerfile that modifies oraclelinux:6.6 to include an Apache HTTP server
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -y install apache2

RUN echo "HTTP server running on guest" > /var/www/html/index.html

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client

EXPOSE 3306
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not correct as you should have a CMD to run at the end.

There are also several best-practises you should include to create less intermediate container snapshots and smaller output:

- you should not run `apt-get` multiple times
- you should run `apt-get update` before running `apt-get install`
- you should clean up after running `apt-get install`
- you should include a maintainer

Try something like:

```
# Dockerfile that modifies oraclelinux:6.6 to include an Apache HTTP server
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Supun Rathnayake

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  apache2 \
  mysql-client \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "HTTP server running on guest" > /var/www/html/index.html

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["your command to run apache"]
```

You should probably look at docker-hub for an apache2 project with lots of downloads and analyse its Dockerfile, that is very instructive.

In principle you can run your mysql client within the same container but that probably requires some scheduler to start both your apache and mysql daemon. Alternatively you should look at putting mysql somewhere else (or use one of the standard containers from Dockerhub and link them to your's).

Comment: Actually, I'd strongly suggest separate containers for `httpd` and `mysql` too.

Comment: @Sobrique Completely right, I misread mysql for sqlite, realised that the OP needed to start that as well, but was not fast enough typing the update.

Comment: Thanks for your updates, Actually I don't know use CMD command. In my scenario what I want to add ? CMD ["......"]

Comment: @SupunRathnayake I am not sure what part of the recommendations you don't understand: 1) go to [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/), [search for apache](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=apache&starCount=0), click the top one of the list [eboraas/apache](https://hub.docker.com/r/eboraas/apache/), click Dockerfile and read the last line `CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]`.

Comment: I mean What is the difference without use CMD in my Dockerfile

Comment: It is what will be executed by default when you execute the contaienr, otherwise you would always have to be provided when bringing a container up.